# WPF usercontrol is missing code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a wpf window and a usercontrol. The WPF window calls the user control. Here is the code:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Simple_Window"

<local:WebBrowserTab x:Name="LeftWebBrowserTab" Grid.Column="0" Margin="32, -4, 0, 0" />
```

The problem is that the usercontrol is being processed. Here is the code:

```
public partial class WebBrowserTab : UserControl
{
    public WebBrowserTab(MainWindow main)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _main = main;
    }
}
```

When opening new windows a new window would be opened differently. Here is the code:

```
NewWindow = new NewWindow(this);
```

How can I add the `this` on the local `local:WebBrowserTab`element?

Comment: I assume you want to pass your mainwindow to the constructor so that your UserComponent can access the MainWindow Attributes/Properties

Comment: That is right, the `this` would be used as a locator. Then the `MainWindow main` can pick up the window.

Comment: I think you're doing this the wrong way, in the case of a user control, you should define several `DependencyProperty` to receive the data you need from the main main window and send the data back. Did you already used the `Bindings` in WPF ?

Comment: If you really do want to do it by passing the mainwindow to the constructor, you'll have to do it fully in the code-behind but that's not how it's supposed to be done i WPF

Comment: Are you sure there is no easy way to send the this?

Comment: There is but you'll have to do the instantiation in the code behind. And you lose the point of using WPF

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a really specific need to use the passed in `Window` in the constructor, it would probably be better to define a `DependencyProperty` (`ParentWindow` in this example) in the `UserControl` instead of the field `_main` you have now and then bind the Window to it.

```
<local:WebBrowserTab ParentWindow="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" x:Name="LeftWebBrowserTab" Grid.Column="0" Margin="32, -4, 0, 0" />
```

Without more context it's not clear why you're doing this but you may also be able to just locate the parent window from inside the control with

```
Window.GetWindow(this);
```

but like the above method you will not be able to use this value in the constructor.